# Why does changing the delegate cause a crash?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have a navigation controller that is its own delegate, and also handles animated transitions:

```
class NavController: UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
  func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    if operation == .push && toVC is GalleryController {
      return self
    }
    return nil
  }

  func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    print("Animation beginning")
    ...
  }

  func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?)
    -> TimeInterval {
      print("transition duration")
      return TimeInterval(0.2)
  }

}
```

This crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in lookupimporforward, called directly by pushViewController.

The transitionDuration() method is called, but not animateTransition().

The problem goes away if I do any of the following:

1. pushViewController with animated = false
2. Change the first method in the above code to always return nil.
3. **Refactor the implementation of UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning to another class and return an instance of that.**

This is counter-intuitive. Do you know why this may be going wrong?

Some more info for debugging:

- The NavController isn't being deallocated (I put a print in deinit).
- Enabling zombies doesn't help.
- Enabling exception breakpoints doesn't help.
- This is on iOS 10.3.

Comment: As per my knowledge in  your case your class will be subclass of **NSObject** like this `class NavController: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. And you'r making class of `UINavigationController.`

Comment: So? Why would that crash?

Comment: check this [Tut](https://www.raywenderlich.com/86521/how-to-make-a-view-controller-transition-animation-like-in-the-ping-app) and just change animation with your animation. Here you check he takes the class of `NSObject` and you'r taking class of `UINavigationController`.

Comment: UINavigationController is a subclass of NSObject, so in both cases, I'm using an NSObject subclass, not that that should have anything to do with the problem.